# I have to install the vim package everytime I reboot the system. Suggest me a way to permanently install vim in my ubuntu (usb)!

Tags: installation, usb, vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

I boot ubuntu from my usb.  The vim package vanishes automatically every time I reboot the system. Is it because I am using a usb to boot ubuntu? Suggest me a way to install the vim package permanently on my usb.

Answer (score 2):

Try this link to set up a persistent usb so that it saves your settings and changes.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert, but it sounds like your USB has a liveCd install (i.e. not persistent). This would mean that most (perhaps all) changes you make will not persist between reboots. I never had much luck with persistent USB installations either.

You could try adding

```
apt-get install vim
```

to the end of the file *~/.bashrc*

I'm not sure that will work though unless your installation logs in automatically as root.